# Error in Update Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Here is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["preconn"].ToString());

   con.Open();

   SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn =" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text, con);

   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salbn", TextBox21.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@basic", TextBox12.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hra", TextBox13.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trvl", TextBox15.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mdeca", TextBox16.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@atnd", TextBox18.Text);
   com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tote", TextBox20.Text);

   com.ExecuteNonQuery();

   con.Close();

   MsgBox("Updated Successfully");

}
```

I got an error:
" Invalid column name 'Group_A'. "
my query is like that
"update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn = Group_A"

Here Group_A is the DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text. I am using asp.net/C#, sql server2008.

Comment: why are you using sql parameters for everything except `DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value needs to be in single quotes.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn ='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "'", con);
```

Having said that, you really should be using parameterized SQL in the WHERE clause like you used everywhere else to prevent SQL Injection attacks.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update slab set salbn = @salbn,basic = @basic,hra = @hra,trvl = @trvl,mdeca = @mdeca,atnd = @atnd,tote = @tote where salbn = @param", con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@param", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text );
```